# Problems Encrypting Mumble Voice Data in C# for UDP

Tags: c#, networking, encryption, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity project using an integrated Mumble client written in C# for voice. I currently have text messaging and sending pings working over TCP. I am now trying to send voice data over UDP but am having issues with encryption.

When sending packets, mumble logs 'Requesting crypt-nonce resync' and sends a request over TCP to the client to resend the client crypt nonce.

I suspect that this means the encryption that I'm using on UDP is incorrect. Mumble's documentation says that the two protocols should use different crypto types. (UDP: OCB-AES128 and TCP: TLSv1)

I am using MumbleSharp, which supports only text messaging without voice, which has UDP in there which is not working.